# Creating a New Command

Tags: math-mode

I am currently working on the following question:

**1)** Create a command that takes a mathematical expression as its sole argument and typesets in
displaystyle.

### The following is what I have interpreted of the question:

```
\newcommand{\M}[1]{$\displaystyle x^2+1$}
\noindent This is the above command \M
```

However, I am getting an error message. I am having a hard type understanding the use of `\displaystyle` in Math Mode.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). If you are getting an error with the above, then the problem is probably related to the fact that you have defined `\M` to have one mandatory parameter (via the `[1]`), but did not provide a parameter to `\M` when you invoked it.  For future reference, It would be helpful if you included a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the actual problem.

Comment: Is this? `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\M}{$$x^2+1$$}
\begin{document}
\noindent This is the above command \M. 

The above command \M\ just works well.
\end{document}
`

Comment: in relation to your last note, it is rather unusual to _ever_ use `\displaystyle` in inline math. As the name implies display style is the style used in display math `\[` or `\begin{align}` etc, so while it can be used in special cases in inline math that is unusual (and defeats the purpose of the inline math styling)

Answer (score 3):

The snippet you have provided almost works.
Possibly, `\M` is taking `\end{document}` as argument, creating problems.
It is therefore good to provide a complete example of the code.

You have defined `\M` to have one user provided parameter, which is not required, since the expression is always the same.
However, mandatory parameters are very useful to construct more versatile commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\M}[1]{$\displaystyle x^2+1$}
\noindent This is the above command \M



\newcommand{\Mm}{$\displaystyle x^3+1$}
\noindent This is the above command \Mm

\newcommand{\Mmm}[1]{$\displaystyle x^{#1}+1$}
\noindent This is the above command \Mmm{4}

\newcommand{\Mmmm}[2]{$\displaystyle x^{#1}+#2$}
\noindent This is the above command \Mmmm{5}{6}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Oh, yes. Very true. Edited. Thx

Comment: May want to remove the `snippet you have provided works`. The code does not report a compile error if there is a blank line after the use of `\M` but not if it is and end of the document.

Comment: @PeterGrill yes that is right. I have edited accordingly